# Finding IP Addresses in File using Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, shell

I want to extract IP addresses present in various files in a folder. I am making use of Python to invoke OS(linux) commands such as strings, grep to achieve that.

Here is the code I have-

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['strings -a -f /root/Downloads/Apps/androidproject/*'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

#p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-E","10.1.1"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-E","'((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#p1.stdout.close()
out = p2.communicate()[0]
print "The IPs are:\n",out
```

The problem I am facing is that Python is not able to evaluate the RE expression I have specified to extract IP addresses from a set of text. I have verified the following things-

> The RE expression is correct and works standalone,
>
> The script is able to find/grep text which is explicitly provided like the line I have in which I am looking for IP's starting from 10.1.1

The problem lies in running the RE expression on the strings output (in the code execution) and am unable to figure out whats wrong. Could use some help.

P.S. I am open to learning an easier, better way to achieve this as well if anyone can suggest.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: hmm, this is a shot in the dark but, try passing your regex as a raw string. instead of "..." do r"..."

Comment: I don't know python well enough to write this, but all of this could be done without shelling out by using File and String apis in Python

Comment: @Nullman That worked!! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: great! but as @JimDeville said, this is most certainly not the pythonic way of doing it

Comment: Agreed, this was just something I needed to do quickly hence took the shorter way. Thanks for the advice @JimDeville